# SQL - primary key choice

Tags: sql, database-design, primary-key

If there is a table ORGANIZATION, can I use license_number as a primary key? I know that the primary key should be immutable, but I don't know if it is so with licenses. Besides, is it possible that two organizations have one license? If no, which primary key should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, about the unique-ness of the company license number, you'll have to check with lawyer in your country.

Anyway, you can always create new, unrelated, ID column (INT IDENTITY) and use it as the primary key and the clustered index key.

Also notice that in SQL Server, the designer makes the primary key column also a clustered index by default. it's not always the best behavior. for example, if you choose the license number as your primary key - it's probably not sequential, which means the database engine will have to insert new rows between existing rows which will cause page splits and high fragmentation of the cluster index, which might affect performance heavily (specially if the table is big one). So, make sure that even if you choose to make the license number your primary key, choose better clustered index key. for example: the date-time when the row created in your table.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not **100 percent** positive that `license_number` is unique, don't use it as a primary key.

The `primary key` should be a unique value which can be used to reference specific rows in a table. To be safe why not use an `auto increment` field?

I would do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE organization
(
organization_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
license_number varchar(100) -- Set accordingly
another_attribute varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (organization_id )
)
```

If `one` organization can have `many` `license numbers` then create another table called `org_license_numbers` and keep track of `organization_id` as a `foreign key` to the `organization` table and the corresponding `license number`

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: don't use *alien* numbers as PK:

- The numbering is not under your control, it could change (maybe a prefix will be added if the key space is exhausted), they could even be brutally renumbered
- since it is not under your controll, uniqueness is not guaranteed. This could also change in time.
- an extra key element could be added, for instance because the same companies could exist in other countries, too
- maybe you don't know the ORGANISATION_id (yet), but you still need to create a record
- The PK *could* function as a foreign key to this table in other tables, changes to the number would cause updates there, too.